# Facebook - get user likes and comments

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the user **likes** and **comments** from facebook?

With the graph api, you can can do `me/likes`, but that only returns the pages you liked, and I want all the likes. So also the url's, posts, pictures, ... I liked. The same for the comments.

Or is there a query to get the activity log from an user?

Comment: It's a very vague question. What exactly you want? Pls mention explicitly.

Comment: I would like to get a summary of all the likes/comments I did the last week.
If you go to your activity log, you get chronological this information. But is it also posible to get this info via the graph api or fql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

- FQL `like` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)
- FQL `comment` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)

to query for object comments and likes. Then, if you want to distinguish between object types  (`photo, album, event, group, note, link, video, application, status, check-in, review, comment, post`) for getting more info about the like or comment, you need to do queries like this for each object type:

```
select src, link from photo where object_id in (select object_id from like where user_id=me() and object_type="photo" limit 25)
```

For URL likes you can use

- FQL `url_like` table https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Graph API. You have to fetch them with different end-points, like:

Get the **posts** with: `/me/feed` - [demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Did)

Perms req: `read_stream`

Get the **photos** with: `/me/photo` - [demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Did)

Perms req: `user_photos`

Now, to get the **likes** use this:

```
/likes?id={post_id|photo_id|url}
```

for **comments**:

```
/comments?id={post_id|photo_id|url}
```

You can test your calls in [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: If I use `/me/feed`, I only get posts I was tagged in.

Comment: No you get all the feeds, any link you've shared, any status update anything

Comment: I want also the posts I liked from other people, not only my own posts.